# I have several nested subscriptions. Any good way to handle the massive indenting?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In the setup of one of my components, I need to make several web service calls. I have something like this:

```
client.getUserProject()
    .subscribe(
        (usersProject) => {
            this.mainProject= usersProject.mainProject;
            client.getRelatedProjects(usersProject.keyWords)
                .subscribe(
                    (relatedProjects) => {
                        this.sanitizeProjects(relatedProjects.projects);
                        client.loadAdditionalAssets(relatedProjects.dependencies)
                            .subscribe(
                                (response3) => {
                                    client.makeCall4(response3.prop)
                                    ...
                                 },
                                 (err) => {
                                    // do something different than the other onErrors
                                 }
                             )
                     },
                     (err) => {
                         // display warning about related projects not being ready and set some flags
                     }
                 )
        },
        (err) => {
            // display an error and prompt the user to reload the page
        }
     )
```

As I get a few layers deep, the indenting is getting a bit crazy. I need to make all these calls, but i was wondering if there was a better/different way to structure this. Things end up getting indented to the point where lines have to be past the 140 mark which is what our guidelines/lint specify.

Does Angular/RXJS support a better way?

Comment: Use two-space indenting?

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify that with [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html):

```
client
    .makeCall1()
    .flatMap(response1 => client.makeCall2(response1.prop))
    .flatMap(response2 => client.makeCall3(response2.prop))
    .flatMap(response3 => client.makeCall4(response3.prop))
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding that documentation. What is this actually doing? Does this still work with the slightly updated OP?

Comment: @user3715648 please give a less contrived example that demonstrates what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: It's fairly accurate to what i'm trying to do. When I make a call, I  want to save part of the response to a property on my component, and use another part of the response to make an additional call. Repeat that process.

Comment: Did you try it? `this` will still be in the correct scope.

Comment: The other issue i'm having while converting my code is the lack of onError callback for each call. Right now I have slightly different logic for onError for some of the calls.

Comment: *"@user3715648 please give a less contrived example that demonstrates what you're actually trying to do."*